# Запись в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Пробую посадить верстку на WordPress.
Столкнулся с проблемой (когда изучал, как выводить записи с помощью php в подвал), что не знаю, где у меня выводятся записи... Прочитал на В-ресс доке, что они все публикуются авт на главной, но у меня на главной странице только а-ля "приветствие" и все такое, а уже далее сайт по навигации будет раскидан на страницу с категориями, в которой по сути будут выводиться записи и публиковаться там. А то сейчас, когда я нажимаю на запись в ВП, то оно просто скидывает меня на главную страницу (в урл пишет что на запись, хотя по сути дела это просто главная, в которой нету места для ее вывода). Так как переместить записи, или какое решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил вопрос сам. для этого нашел в интернете такую вот приятную штуку - wphierarchy.com Если кто столкнулся с проблемой, что где выводится и в каком порядке, то думаю там вы найдете ответ.